# How to get algorithm field from signed PE PKCS#7 block

Tags: encryption, openssl, sha, pkcs#7, asn.1

I've got `PKCS#7` content extracted from PE file.

The first part before the certificate chain (goes from the beginning up to the `cert:` label), contains info about the file integrity.

In particular, the hash that matches the file hash and the algorithm that use to generate this hash (worth `FA0FE65F973A5709DC04EE18ABEF353EBEFEA669` and `sha1` correspondingly on the example listed below).

I'm using `openssl` and I'd like to extract the hash algorithm type from the `X509` format. I tried something like printing md_algs struct from debugger, and hopefully find the field `algorithm` worth `1.3.14.3.2.26` but that's what I saw..

```
p *(Pkcs7->d.sign->md_algs)
(stack_st_X509_ALGOR) $6 = {
  stack = {
     num = 1
     data = 0x00000001024457f0
     sorted = 0
     num_alloc = 4
     comp = 0x0000000000000000
  }
}
```

Where can I see the algorithm field ?

P.s. here's the relevant part of the pkcs7 struct :

```
PKCS7: 
   type: pkcs7-signedData (1.2.840.113549.1.7.2)
   d.sign: 
     version: 1
     md_algs:
       algorithm: sha1 (1.3.14.3.2.26)
       parameter: NULL
     contents: 
       type: undefined (1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.4)
     d.other: SEQUENCE:
        0:d=0  hl=2 l=  60 cons: SEQUENCE          
        2:d=1  hl=2 l=  23 cons:  SEQUENCE          
        4:d=2  hl=2 l=  10 prim:   OBJECT            :1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.15
       16:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 cons:   SEQUENCE          
       18:d=3  hl=2 l=   1 prim:    BIT STRING        
       21:d=3  hl=2 l=   4 cons:    cont [ 0 ]        
       23:d=4  hl=2 l=   2 cons:     cont [ 2 ]        
       25:d=5  hl=2 l=   0 prim:      cont [ 0 ]        
       27:d=1  hl=2 l=  33 cons:  SEQUENCE          
       29:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 cons:   SEQUENCE          
       31:d=3  hl=2 l=   5 prim:    OBJECT            :sha1
       38:d=3  hl=2 l=   0 prim:    NULL              
       40:d=2  hl=2 l=  20 prim:   OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:FA0FE65F973A5709DC04EE18ABEF353EBEFEA669
     cert:
      cert_info: 
      ...
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defined in [`pkcs7.h`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1/include/openssl/pkcs7.h#L61), the `md_algs` attribute that you are inspecting is a stack of `X509_ALGOR` instances:

```
typedef struct pkcs7_signed_st {
    ASN1_INTEGER *version;      /* version 1 */
    STACK_OF(X509_ALGOR) *md_algs; /* md used */
    STACK_OF(X509) *cert;       /* [ 0 ] */
    STACK_OF(X509_CRL) *crl;    /* [ 1 ] */
    STACK_OF(PKCS7_SIGNER_INFO) *signer_info;
    struct pkcs7_st *contents;
} PKCS7_SIGNED;
```

It can be safely accessed via the [OpenSSL Stack API](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/STACK_API), for example using the function `sk_X509_ALGOR_value()` to inspect its element(s).

`X509_ALGOR` itself is defined in [`x509.h`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1/include/openssl/x509.h#L59):

```
struct X509_algor_st {
    ASN1_OBJECT *algorithm;
    ASN1_TYPE *parameter;
} /* X509_ALGOR */ ;
```

The information you are looking for is stored in the property `algorithm`, which you can inspect using, for example, [`OBJ_obj2txt()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/OBJ_obj2txt.html).

Tying it together, to get a textual representation of the first algorithm in the stack, you could do something like this:

```
char tbuf[20];
X509_ALGOR *algor = sk_X509_ALGOR_value(Pkcs7->d.sign->md_algs, 0);
int res = OBJ_obj2txt(tbuf, sizeof tbuf, algor->algorithm, 0);
```

After that, `tbuf` should contain a value like `"sha1"` and `res` contains the length of that string. For programmatic purposes, a function like `OBJ_obj2nid()` is probably more useful.

---

The debugger did not give you this information because the `data` field in the `stack` element is not strongly typed. You would have to cast it yourself to indicate that it is an array of pointers to `X509_ALGOR` structs. The OpenSSL Stack API provides you a set of macros that do the casting for you and access the array that way. And then, the `ASN1_OBJECT` that you end up with is hard to inspect or interpret in the debugger since it is just a bunch of bytes representing an object id in `ASN.1` format.